# Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider)

Tags: asp.net, file, http, asp.net-web-api

I'm using ASP.NET Web API. I have the following code which saves the incoming file, then gets the filename.

```
MultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files"));
Task<IEnumerable<HttpContent>> task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

return task.ContinueWith<string>(contents =>
{ 
    string filename = provider.BodyPartFileNames.First().Value;
```

When I run this when hosted, I get the correct filename, but it doesn't seem the file is being saved.

*File.Exists(filename)* returns false.

This works fine locally though. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated (been on this the whole day...)

Let me know if you'd like more info.

Thanks.

Comment: It's working in a dev environment but not outside of it? I would first look at write permissions for your NetworkService, IIS_IUSRS, or whatever user is doing the writing for your web API. You might want to look at your request in Fiddler to make sure your file looks OK on the way up.

Comment: @SteveHook I figured out what the problem was, and forgot to update this post. But you're right on - it's a permissions problem (which still don't get why why because I can save to that path just fine with my other code that saves from an asp:file upload control)